# React Draft.js Wysiwyg: How to programmatically insert text at the cursor location?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs, draft-js-plugins, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am using the [React Draft Wysiwyg](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/) and I need to insert arbitrary text from one component of my application into the editor component. I am doing this via the clipboard as an intermediary for the transfer from one component to the other. But the `document.execCommand('paste')` fails.

Does anybody know how to do this?

My sample code is here; the third console log emits false for the paste result.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { EditorState, convertToRaw, Modifier } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';
import htmlToDraft from 'html-to-draftjs';
import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';

class EditorConvertToHTML extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});
    this.setEditor = (editor) => {
      this.editor = editor;
    };
    this.focusEditor = () => {
      if (this.editor) {
        this.editor.focusEditor();
        console.log("1. Editor has the focus now");
      }
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.focusEditor();
  }

  onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState,
    });
  };

  sendTextToEditor = (text) => {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('value', text);
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.select();
    var result = document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(input);

    navigator.clipboard.readText()
    .then(text => {
      this.focusEditor();
      console.log('2. Retrieved pasted text from clipboard = ', text);
      result = document.execCommand('paste');
      console.log("3. Paste command's result = ", result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', err);
    });

    return result;
  }

  render() {
    const { editorState } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <EditorStyled>
          <Editor
            ref={this.setEditor}
            editorState={editorState}
            wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
            editorClassName="demo-editor"
            onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
          />
        </EditorStyled>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.sendTextToEditor.bind(this, 'Sample text to put in editor')}>Copy sample text to editor</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default EditorConvertToHTML;

const EditorStyled = styled.div`
  width: ${() => "calc(100% - 40px)"};
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
`;
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to Rosemarie Robertson's explanations/article @ https://dev.to/rose/draft-js-simple-content-manipulation-b7a I got the sample working. Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { EditorState, Modifier } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';

// Following sample is based the article https://dev.to/rose/draft-js-simple-content-manipulation-b7a

class EditorConvertToHTML extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.focusEditor();
  }

  setEditor = (editor) => {
    this.editor = editor;
  };

  focusEditor = () => {
    if (this.editor) {
      this.editor.focusEditor();
      console.log("1. Editor has the focus now");
    }
  };

  onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState,
    });
  };

  sendTextToEditor = (text) => {
    this.setState({editorState: this.insertText(text, this.state.editorState)});
    this.focusEditor();
  }

  insertText = (text, editorState) => {
    const currentContent = editorState.getCurrentContent(),
          currentSelection = editorState.getSelection();

    const newContent = Modifier.replaceText(
      currentContent,
      currentSelection,
      text
    );

    const newEditorState = EditorState.push(editorState, newContent, 'insert-characters');
    return  EditorState.forceSelection(newEditorState, newContent.getSelectionAfter());
  }

  render() {
    const { editorState } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <EditorStyled>
          <Editor
            ref={this.setEditor}
            editorState={editorState}
            wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
            editorClassName="demo-editor"
            onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
          />
        </EditorStyled>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.sendTextToEditor.bind(this, 'Sample text to put in editor')}>Copy sample text to editor</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default EditorConvertToHTML;

const EditorStyled = styled.div`
  width: ${() => "calc(100% - 40px)"};
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
`;
```

Comment:  yay I'm glad it helped!

Comment: I'm trying to get this working with Formik (editor state is passed into EditorConvertToHTML as prop) and I can't get it to update the editor content. I'm noticing that `insertText` produces correct output, but onChange event always maintains old value when fired after button click (state and text are updated when user is typing though, via onChange). 

Any suggestion how could I solve this issue? 

I've did some reading and I think it's because of race condition, but couldn't solve it.

Comment: This function does not preserve the current inline style. Please look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68874857/how-to-insert-text-programmaticaly-into-draft-js-rich-text-field-while-maintaini/68883262#68883262 if you'd like the function to take into account such behavior.