# How to add text based on click which is outside the Editor component , to the Editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

what I have tried ,
here i have added two button when user click value stores in state, than that state is passed to the editor , copy as a props . then I was trying to convert value to html code and then concat the copy prop then again convert to html to draft format, and then update the state, but i am not able to fix.

Codesandbox link : [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-phoebe-ltiwb?file=/src/App.js:136-722)

what i want when user click on button it should append with the text value in editor.

**Able to add text based on clicked, but now problem is to append text based on cursor position , currently it adds to the end, i want to be added where the user points the cursor and then click the button it should be added there**

Latest code : [Updated code with  add text functionality](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-https-c28gh)

**Parent Component**

```
import EditorWrapper from "./Editor";

export default function App() {
  const [copy, setCopy] = useState("");
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="d-flex">
          <button
            onClick={() => setCopy("Welcome")}
            className="btn btn-primary me-2"
          >
            Welcome
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={() => setCopy("Thank you")}
            className="btn btn-primary"
          >
            Thank you
          </button>
        </div>
        <EditorWrapper copy={copy} />
      </div>
    </>
```

**Editor Component**

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import { EditorState, ContentState, convertToRaw } from "draft-js";
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";
import htmlToDraft from "html-to-draftjs";
import draftToHtml from "draftjs-to-html";

export default function EditorWrapper({ copy }) {
  const initialState = () => EditorState.createEmpty();

  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(initialState);

  const onChange = async (value) => {
    // const data = draftToHtml(convertToRaw(value.getCurrentContent()));
    // console.log(data.concat(`<p>${copy}</p>`));

    // const contentBlock = htmlToDraft(data);
    // const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
    //   contentBlock?.contentBlocks
    // );

    // const updateState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
    setEditorState(value);
  };
  return (
    <Editor
      editorState={editorState}
      toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
      wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
      editorClassName="editorClassName"
      onEditorStateChange={(value) => onChange(value)}
      stripPastedStyles
      ariaLabel="draftEditor"
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with draftjs, but looking at your code, I think you logged `data.concat(`<p>${copy}</p>`)` to the console and forgot actually adding it to `data` variable.

Comment: that doesn't work, i have converted the data into draft format and then passed it  to setEditorstate(updateState )

Comment: Able to add the feature but now the problem is , can't add text to the particular position its always adds to end of the string because of concat method, please provide a solution based on cursor position

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-brattain-u9cqi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: React Draft.js Wysiwyg: How to programmatically insert text at the cursor location?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657399/react-draft-js-wysiwyg-how-to-programmatically-insert-text-at-the-cursor-locati

Answer (score 0):

**Parent Component**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { EditorState, Modifier } from "draft-js";
import EditorComponent from "./Editor";

const App = () => {
  const initialState = () => EditorState.createEmpty();
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(initialState);

  const sendTextToEditor = (text) => {
    setEditorState(insertText(text, editorState));
  };

  const insertText = (text, editorValue) => {
    const currentContent = editorValue.getCurrentContent();
    const currentSelection = editorValue.getSelection();

    const newContent = Modifier.replaceText(
      currentContent,
      currentSelection,
      text
    );

    const newEditorState = EditorState.push(
      editorValue,
      newContent,
      "insert-characters"
    );
    return EditorState.forceSelection(
      newEditorState,
      newContent.getSelectionAfter()
    );
  };
  const buttonValue = ["welcome", "Thank you", "react"];

  return (
    <div>
      {buttonValue.map((i) => (
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          key={i}
          type="button"
          onClick={() => sendTextToEditor(i)}
        >
          {i}
        </button>
      ))}
      <EditorComponent
        editorState={editorState}
        setEditorState={setEditorState}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

**Editor Component**

```
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";

const EditorComponent = ({ editorState, setEditorState }) => {
  const onChange = async (value) => {
    setEditorState(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
        wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
        editorClassName="editorClassName"
        onEditorStateChange={(value) => {
          onChange(value);
        }}
        stripPastedStyles
        ariaLabel="draftEditor"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default EditorComponent;
```

Refer [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-sun-ktc3k)